# Android Firebase database limitolast 10 but add up

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to connect the Firebase real-time database as a database to my app's chats. I know that I can limit the entries that I access to last 10 entries by calling `limitToLast(10)` function to my Firebase reference.

The problem I have right now is that when I do this, it will limit that reference to always display the last 10 entries even if I add more entries from my app. However, I would want it to count up as I add more entries to my app. So, for instance, if I add 2 more entries, my chat list would show 12 entries and so on.

Here's my code so far with that `limitToLast(10)` added.

```
DatabaseReference tRef = database.getReference(getString(R.string.firebase_channel));
tRef.limitToLast(10).addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
            Chat c = dataSnapshot.getValue(Chat.class);
            chatAdapter.newChat(c, dataSnapshot.getKey());
            Log.d(TAG, "onChildAdded\t" + c.asChat());
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
            Chat c = dataSnapshot.getValue(Chat.class);
            chatAdapter.modifyChat(c, dataSnapshot.getKey());
            Log.d(TAG, "onChildChanged\t" + c.asChat());
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Chat c = chatAdapter.removeChat(dataSnapshot.getKey());
            Log.d(TAG, "onChildRemoved\t" + c.asChat());
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
            Chat c = dataSnapshot.getValue(Chat.class);
            chatAdapter.moveChat(c, dataSnapshot.getKey());
            Log.d(TAG, "onChildMoved\t" + c.asChat());
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onCancelled\t" + databaseError.toException());
            Toast.makeText(context, "error loading chat list", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

What came through my mind is to actually separate the chat lists into one with which I show in my app and one with which is connected to Firebase, so when a new entry is added in my app, I'll add that to both lists. But I really don't think that using up this extra memory is the solution to this issue. Is there any way to resolve this issue otherwise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only ever want to add items, how about simply ignoring `onChildRemoved`?

Comment: So you are suggesting that since I'm only concerned with adding items, I leave the other overridden methods empty? I guess that's a solution for now. However in the future what if I want to delete some items as well?

Comment: I specifically mention `onChildRemoved`, since that is the only behavior you seem to be trying to ignore.

Comment: yes yes I understood that and thank you for that since that solved my current issue at hand. However I was just wondering what I would do if I had to care about removals as well